# Excel [h]:mm duration to pandas timedelta

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am importing data from an Excel worksheet where I have a 'Duration' field displayed in [h]:mm (so that the total number of hours is shown).  I understand that underneath, this is simply number of days as a float.

I want to work with this as a `timedelta` column or similar in a Pandas dataframe but no matter what I do it's dropping any hours over 24 (e.g. the days portion).

Excel data (over 24 hours highlighted):

[image: Excel data with duration over 24 hours]

Pandas import (1d 7h 51m):

```
     BATCH_NO             Duration
354      7154             04:36:00
465      7270             06:35:00
466      7271             08:05:00
467      7272             05:54:00
468      7273             09:10:00
472      7277             06:15:00
476      7280             10:23:00
477      7284             06:09:00
499      7313             06:46:00
503      7322             05:27:00
510      7333             14:15:00
515      7335  1900-01-01 07:51:00
516      7338             07:51:00
517      7339             09:00:00
518      7339             05:29:00
519      7339             09:00:00
520      7339             05:29:00
522      7342             12:10:00
525      7343             08:00:00
530      7346             08:25:00
```

Running a `to_datetime` conversion simply drops the day (integer) part of the column:

```
     BATCH_NO  Duration
354      7154  04:36:00
465      7270  06:35:00
466      7271  08:05:00
467      7272  05:54:00
468      7273  09:10:00
472      7277  06:15:00
476      7280  10:23:00
477      7284  06:09:00
499      7313  06:46:00
503      7322  05:27:00
510      7333  14:15:00
515      7335  07:51:00
516      7338  07:51:00
517      7339  09:00:00
518      7339  05:29:00
519      7339  09:00:00
520      7339  05:29:00
522      7342  12:10:00
525      7343  08:00:00
530      7346  08:25:00
```

I have tried importing by fixing the dtype as `float`, but only `str` or `object` work - `dtype={'Duration': str}` works.

`float` gives the error `float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.time'` and even with `str` or `object`, Python still thinks the column i a `datetime.time`

Ideally I do not want to change the Excel source data or export to .csv as in intermediate step.

Comment: Can you provide the DataFrame as dictionary after the import to pandas? Can you also try to set the type as timedelta? Try `'<m8[ns]'`

Comment: Hi @mozway, if I try ```dtype={'Duration': '<m8[ns]'}``` on the import, I get ```ValueError: Unable to convert column Duration to type timedelta64[ns]```.

If I import as ```object``` and try casting, I get ```ValueError: Invalid type for timedelta scalar: <class 'datetime.time'>```.  With import as ```str``` the error is ```ValueError: only leading negative signs are allowed```.

I'm afraid I'm not sure what you mean by 'provide the DataFrame as dictionary after the import to pandas' - for info, I have more than these columns - removed the rest for clarity.

Comment: That would be `df[['your_col']].to_dict()`

Comment: So, ```...dtype={'Duration': object}...
df['Duration']= df[['Duration']].to_dict()
df['Duration'] = df['Duration'].astype('<m8[ns]')```
gives ```timedelta64[ns]``` and will not throw an error but the result is that Duration ends up as ```NaT```.  Similar with ```dtype={'Duration': object}``` gives ```NaN```

Comment: Hmm, tricky without having a real example.

Comment: Hopefully this works.  Excel data is at https://github.com/ChemEnger/pandas/blob/3160ca7610959bd9a691c720579440deaf49fc2b/Duration%20data.xlsx and Python 'Duration import.py' is https://github.com/ChemEnger/pandas/blob/3160ca7610959bd9a691c720579440deaf49fc2b/Duration%20import.py

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250540/discussion-between-chemenger-and-mozway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it correctly, the imported objects are `datetime` and `time` with the datetime in Julian calendar.

So you must convert with a custom function:

```
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta

def convert(t):
    if isinstance(t, time):
        t = datetime.combine(datetime.min, t)
    delta = t-datetime.min
    if delta.days != 0:
        delta -= timedelta(days=693594)
    return delta

df['Duration'].apply(convert)
```

Output:

```
0    0 days 04:36:00
1    0 days 06:35:00
2    0 days 08:05:00
3    0 days 05:54:00
4    0 days 09:10:00
5    0 days 06:15:00
6    0 days 10:23:00
7    0 days 06:09:00
8    0 days 06:46:00
9    0 days 05:27:00
10   0 days 14:15:00
11   1 days 07:51:00  # corrected
12   0 days 07:51:00
13   0 days 09:00:00
14   0 days 05:29:00
15   0 days 09:00:00
...
```

Comment: Spot on, thank you!  Duration needs importing as ```object``` or left alone; no ```to_dict()``` conversion.  I'm after minutes duration, so followed up with
```df['Minutes'] = df['Duration'].dt.total_seconds() / 60```